# The getter 'errorMessage' isn't defined for the type 'ApiErrorDialog Function()'.?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class ApiErrorDialog extends StatefulWidget {
  final errorCode;
  final errorMessage;

  const ApiErrorDialog(
      {Key? key, required this.errorCode, required this.errorMessage})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ApiErrorDialogState createState() => _ApiErrorDialogState();
}

class _ApiErrorDialogState extends State<ApiErrorDialog> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      body: WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () async {
          return false;
        },
        child: AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Something went wrong'),
          content: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text('Response Code: ' + widget.errorCode),
              SizedBox(
                height: 4,
              ),
              Text('Response Message: ' + widget.errorMessage),
            ],
          ),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Phoenix.rebirth(context);
              },
              child: Text(
                'Restart App',
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

> hello guys, Im new to flutter and Im facing issue with error "The getter 'errorMessage' & 'errorCode' isn't defined for the type 'ApiErrorDialog Function()'. ?". I tried but i was not able to solve it. Also someone i know suggested me this should be null safety related issue. please help me.

Comment: Abhijeet your question is not clear, plz share full or bare minimal reproducible code

Comment: Text('Response Code: ' + widget.errorCode) and Text('Response Message: ' + widget.errorMessage)  these two lines are showing errors message "The getter 'errorMessage' & 'errorCode' isn't defined for the type 'ApiErrorDialog Function()'".

Comment: and actually i also didn't understand the problem because till last week it was working fine.

Comment: the issue can be as little as a single typo, but no one will be able to help with this half code...
as it is not clear how you've created the constructor, plus you should also put the code where you're calling it

Comment: #iamdipanshus please check once more I have updated the code

Comment: well, this should've occurred for the case when `errorCode` and `errorMessage` is not defined in the constructor itself, but this is not the case here... and I tried running it as well... and it's working fine for me